# Negative charged intermediate in acidic conditions - what's the problem?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, carbonyl-compounds

Why positively charged intermediates are preferred over negative charged intermediates, when formed during a reaction taking place in acidic conditions?

For example:

[image]
Image source: *Organic Chemistry by David R. Klein*

Here, per *Organic Chemistry by David R. Klein* says,

> That is, the mechanism does not exhibit any negative charges, which is
>   consistent with acidic conditions.

**Why?**

Comment: What do you think happens to negatively charged species under acidic conditions?

Comment: What happens to a positively charged one? I am missing somewhere.

Comment: Well, cations containing hydrogen are usually quite acidic and anions basic, aren't they?

Answer (score 3):

*Acidic conditions* — whether you are using the Brønsted or the Arrhenius definition of *acidity* — is characterised by readily available protons. Remember the general dissolution ionisation of a Brønsted acid in water  as shown below:

$$\ce{HA + H2O <=> H3O+ + A-}\tag{1}$$

The proton is readily liberated and transferred to species which are more happy to accept it — for strong acids, that means it is transferred to water, a really weak base. A proton typically gladly attaches to anything that has a negative charge, because those species are typically more basic than water in this example. Therefore, postulating an enolate or any other oxygen-centred anion in acidic solution is not considered correct since there will be enough protons to quench it.

However, this does not mean that *no* anions can exist in aquaeous solution. For example, a typical method to transform alcohols into iodides is refluxing in aquaeous hydrogen iodide. Here, $\ce{HI}$ is a very strong acid that very readily dissociates to give iodide anions, $\ce{I-}$. These, even though negatively charged, *do* exist in acidic conditions and are able to attack nucleophilicly. That’s all due to the high acidity of $\ce{HI}$.

$$\ce{R-OH + H3O+ + I- <<=> R-OH2+ + H2O + I- -> R-I + 2 H2O}\tag{2}$$